# Counting the number of elements in the set $\{ x^{13n}:n \mbox{ is a positive integer}\}$ under certain conditions

Tags: group-theory

A cyclic group of order $15$ has an element $x$ such that the set $\{x^3,x^5,x^9 \}$ has exactly two elements. How many elements are in the set $\{ x^{13n}:n \mbox{ is a positive integer}\}$?

I feel like some form of $\textbf{gcd}$ or $\textbf{lcm}$ is involved, but I could be wrong. Any form of hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if the set $\{x^3,x^5,x^9\}$ has exactly two elements, one of them must be the identity (why?). Hence, apply Lagrange.

Comment: @Zen thanks for the hints. Rather than one of them being the identity, why can't one of them equal another?

Comment: One of them must equal another - that is your premise no? In fact, the ones that are equal must both be equal to the identity.

Comment: @Zen Thank you. Things are not that clear right now but I'll keep thinking about this question.

Comment: Suppose none of them is the identity. Then you have either $x^3=x^5\implies x^2=e$ which implies you have a subgroup of order 2, which by Lagrange's is impossible. Or you have $x^5=x^9\implies x^4=e$, also impossible. [edited: I had a brain fart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**: The group is cyclic, and of order $15$. Keep in mind that one of $x^3,x^5,x^9$ is distinct from the other two, so we certainly can't have $x=e$.

If $x^3=x^9,$ then $x^6=e$, but the order of $x$ must divide the order of the group (and also divide $6$, in this case), and so the order of $x$ is $3$.

Show that the other two cases are impossible.

Thus, $x$ has order $3.$ What can we then say about the number of distinct values that powers of $x$ can take? Since $13n$ ranges through all values (*modulo* $3$) for positive integers $n$, what can we say about the number of values that $x^{13n}$ *does* take?